# Do I need to place .c files in my R package?

Tags: r, c

Perhaps a naive question, but I am building an `R` package and wanted to know if my package depends on code that has been written in C, do I need to include the .c files or can I just include the .so files?

Comment: The typical way packages are distributed is as source packages, which means *yes*, you need to include the `.c` files in the package. A binary package includes the `.so` files (or `.lib` or `.dll`, depending on the OS), but I don't know of any packages that are distributed solely as binary packages.

Comment: As an example, if you install a package such as `dplyr` (and use `type="source"`, the default for non-windows), then you'll see `gcc` commands compiling the `./src/` files into shared libraries.

Comment: I think to get it on CRAN you have to provide the .c files. ( I mean how on earth would you provide the right .so file for every user/os...?)

Comment: @r2evans makes sense. You say the typical way is a source package, but does R support binary packages as well? I suppose you do say that you don't know of any...

Comment: R *does* support binary packages, and windows defaults to installing them by default. What I said is that I don't know of any package that is distributed ***solely*** as a binary package, everything (if I recall correctly) is distributed either as source or as source+binary. If you install from CRAN, then they often have both; if you install with (say) `devtools::install_github`, it installs by source and compiles it. One gotcha: often source packages on CRAN are available days (or more) before their respective binary packages, so often for leading edge, one must install source packages.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for all that info!